# Правильная разработка веб-сайта

Tags: php, веб-программирование, веб-сервер

Всем доброго времени суток. Много уже поработал с различными api. Пришло время самому написать хороший проект. Появились такие идеи:

1. Отдельно написать api, отдельно написать web-интерфейс (в моём случае два отдельных проекта на Laravel). Принцип работы такой: например клиент перешёл на вкладку новостей, Controller на веб-клиенте посылает `curl` на маршрут вида `www.mydomain.com/api`получает ответ в формате `json` - парсит и вывод свой view.
2. Второй вариант - всё лепить в одном проекте. Не представляю как это `элегантно` сделать.

Прошу вашей помощи в следующих вопросах:

- Какой вариант выбрать ? (лично я склоняюсь к первому).
- Не будет ли проблемно для любого пользовательского интерфейса каждый раз отправлять запрос к `api-серверу` ?
- Как правильно спроектировать авторизацию/регистрацию ?

Благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: второй вариант...

Comment: @Manitikyl, ну зачем же вы так категорично

Comment: Первый вариант выбирайте, но делайте архитектуру такой, что сможете перейти ко 2 варианту, поменяв несколько классов. Не проблематичнее, чем любое другое api. Авторизацию/регистрацию через api, по токену.

Comment: @ArchDemon на счёт первого сомневаюсь. Вдруг когда-то понадобится другой веб-интерфейс, или же приложение под `телефон Андрея`.

Comment: Ну так у вас api. К нему можно любой интерфейс прикрепить. Хоть веб, хоть телефон, хоть десктоп на c++. Если вам нужно одновременно и веб и телефон, то вы не тот стэк технологий выбрали